# How can I get input elements using inputmask to not revert changes to the previous value when using them within a table sorted with tablesorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, jquery-inputmask

I have been spending a fair amount of time working on an issue with input elements, which are using inputmask, within a table sorted using tablesorter.

When the user enters an input in the masked field *after* the `updateRows` event has been triggered and then changes focus, the masked field will revert the content to the previously entered value.

I have poured through the documentation of both plugins to figure a workaround, but I have not found a suitable solution. I realize that there are other ways to work around this issue, however I have ajax code (for autosaving each row separately) that would require a rewrite that I do not wish to do if it could be avoided.

Any help would be appreciated.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5bqyod6j/1/

Code:

```html
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='sorter-inputs'>Col 1</th>
      <th class='sorter-inputs'>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="control"><input type="text" class='money' value='25' form='f-1'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="control"><input type="text" value='test2' form='f-1'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="control"><input type="text" class='money' value='12' form='f-2'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="control"><input type="text" value='another 2' form='f-2'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="control"><input type="text" class='money' value='89' form='f-3'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="control"><input type="text" value='val-2' form='f-3'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- These are part of the ajax functionality -->
  <form action="" id="f-1"></form>
  <form action="" id="f-2"></form>
  <form action="" id="f-3"></form>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tablesorter@2.31.3/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" integrity="sha256-dtGH1XcAyKopMui5x20KnPxuGuSx9Rs6piJB/4Oqu6I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tablesorter@2.31.3/dist/js/parsers/parser-input-select.min.js" integrity="sha256-ugEATjydQqCNpuca1CGyiLVdN9N6uuouP2CkIL7Dr1k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask@5.0.6/dist/jquery.inputmask.js" integrity="sha256-E9pFDiHlfB3afd46AyTqvmjcSv7VREgs5Y5e8TBECU0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $('#table').tablesorter()
  $('.money').inputmask('currency', {
    autoUnmask: true,
    groupSeparator: ',',
    allowMinus: true,
    digits: 2,
    placeholder: '_',
    inputMode: 'decimal'
  })
  $('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
    $('#table').trigger('updateRows')
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It lies within js/parsers/parser-input-select.js. It appears to attach some handlers at inopportune times to play nice with inputmask. Writing a custom parser or text extractor and updating the table at a better time seems to work well enough.

I have also discovered that even loading said file and not even using the parsers at all will trigger the bug.